# How to use ExclusionConstraint with inline_formset that may already remove invalid records?

Tags: django, django-models

I am using `django.contrib.postgres.field.DateRangeField` in a model with an exclusion constraint to make sure 2 dateranges don't overlap:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date_range = DateRangeField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
        ExclusionConstraint(
            name='exclude_overlapping_periods',
            expressions=[
                ('date_range', RangeOperators.OVERLAPS),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

This works, but fails ugly with an `integrityError` (as it should).

I want to validate the model with a clean method to make a user friendly response:

```
    def clean(self):
        error_dict = {}

        if MyModel.objects.exclude(id=self.id).filter(
            date_range__overlap=self.date_range):

            error_dict['date_range'] = ValidationError(
            'Range can not overlap with an existing period.',
            code='overlap_period')

        if error_dict:
        raise ValidationError(error_dict)
```

This works, but not in the instance when I use a `inline_formset` and one instance is deleted at the same time another is updated.

I want to allow a inline_formset to delete some records and udpate others (that may have overlapped with the previous deleted record), yet still maintain the exclusion on all records not deleted.

> The problem appears to be that `clean` and `validate_unique` are
> called (obviously) before saving the model. This means that the
> deleted records are not removed before the validation, so an error is
> always thrown.

How can I accomodate this?

Comment: You could work with a transaction such that either the view succeeds completely, or fails completelyl.

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem please could you explain what you mean by a transaction? I want to allow a formset to delete some records and udpate others (that may have overlapped with the previous deleted record).

Comment: @alias51 did you find a clean solution to your problem?